# VBA - A message "Delete?" comes up by itself while looping to protect sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

During a loop (For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets, code below)... There are 38 sheets.  Two of them has this message popped up..??  It's a message from Excel, not me.... why?  What does this mean?

```
 n = Worksheets.count:  count_X = 0
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     ws.Unprotect Password:=str_PW
     ws.Protect Password:=PW, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True:  Application.EnableEvents = True:  Application.Cursor = xlWait
     ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
     count_X = count_X + 1
     If (count_X = n) Then Sleep 88
     Sheets("XX").Range("E7").Value = count_X:                      Sleep 11
     If (count_X = n) Then Sleep 444

     MsgBox "Protect... " & ws.Name   '<<< This is my way of finding out which two sheets!! OMG...

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False:  Application.EnableEvents = False:  Application.Cursor = xlWait
 Next ws

 Sheets
```

[image]

Comment: If it's only two of the sheets, maybe there's something about them? Any more information you could give us?

Comment: Christofer, I followed your advice "it's only two sheets"... so I deleted these two sheets, setup two new to replace (redo formulas, etc.).  The message error went away.  Very weird!!  Probably no one came across this error message before.  Thanks again!